# How to create a vector of positions of a numeric vector in R?

Tags: r, sorting, vector

I have a vector of numbers that contain some gaps. For example,

```
vec <- c(3,1,7,3,5,7)
```

So, there are 4 different values and I would like to transform it into a vector of values (without gaps) indicating the order of the entry while respecting the same position. So, in this case, I would like to obtain

```
2 1 4 2 3 4
```

Indicating a sequence of between 1 and 4 and showing the orders in the original vector `vec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` to help you look up the values in a sorted unique order. For example

```
vec <- c(3,1,7,3,5,7)
match(vec, sort(unique(vec)))
# [1] 2 1 4 2 3 4
```

This works because match returns the indexes which will start at 1.

Comment: Perfect! It seems I need to wait 5 more minutes to accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `factor`

```
as.integer(factor(vec))
[1] 2 1 4 2 3 4
```

Comment: Great alternative.